# input control type date with datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

my html I use a

```
<input runat="server" id="dateid" maxlength="50" size="10" type="date" name="dateid" />
```

I have a jquery date picker that I am using so the first issue was on certain browsers such as google chrome it provides its own date picker. I read to not use input type date but this way simplifies my jquery code to apply a calendar to all dates. So then I found modernizr which seems to work it does not show my calendar when the browser supports its own calendar.

I am using modernizr version 2.6.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if (!Modernizr.inputtypes['date']) {
                $('input[type="date"]').datepicker();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

the main issue now if I allow google chromes calendar to be used when I click a date it does not get applied to my input control. I click the date it shows up in the input control but then once i click away it goes back to not having a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers like Chrome will render the date `input` field as an `HTML5 Standart Date Calendar`. Change the input type to **text** and add a data- **attribute** to tell that Its a date picker:

HTML

```
<input runat="server" 
 id="dateid" 
 maxlength="50" 
 size="10" 
 type="text" 
 name="dateid" 
 data-datepicker="true"/>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('input[data-datepicker="true"]').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```